# oracle.web or oracle.database

Tags: .net, oracle

does anyone know the difference between these two assemblies?  Is the web assembly just better data access tools for the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oracle.Web](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10928_01/IntroOverview.htm#BHCHIBEF) providers ASP.NET's System.Web using Oracle as the backend.

> Oracle Providers for ASP.NET is a
>   collection of ASP.NET 2.0 providers
>   that follow the ASP.NET 2.0 provider
>   model and uses Oracle Database as the
>   data source.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10928_01/IntroAssemblyandClassList.htm

Not sure what oracle.database is.